# round to 2 decimal places in js invoice

Tags: javascript

i have my invoice js script done and working, but i cant figure out how to round the grand total to 2 decimal spaces.

js:

```
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var item1 = document.getElementById('item1');
var item2 = document.getElementById('item2');
var item3 = document.getElementById('item3');

item.onchange = function() {
        price.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
        qty.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
        add();
    };
    qty.onchange = function() {
        add();
    }
item1.onchange = function() {
        price1.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
        qty1.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
        add();
    };
    qty1.onchange = function() {
        add();
    }
item2.onchange = function() {
        price2.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
        qty2.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
        add();
    };
    qty2.onchange = function() {
        add();
    }
item3.onchange = function () {
        price3.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
        qty3.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
        add();
    };
    qty3.onchange = function() {
        add();
    }
  function add() {
      var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        var sum = 0;
        var price = (parseFloat(selects[i].value) )?parseFloat(selects[i].value):0;
        var qty = (parseFloat(inputs[i].value) )?parseFloat(inputs[i].value):0;
        sum += price * qty;
        total += sum * 1.06
        if(i == 0){
          document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "$" + sum;
        }else{

          document.getElementById('result'+i).innerHTML = "$" + sum;
        }             
      };

      document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML = "$" + total;
  }
```

ive tried 3 or 4 methods, but due to my lack of experience with js, i just cant get right

Comment: Please Please Please and more Please - DO NOT USE FLOATS FOR MONEY. Store things in cents (integers). People get funny over their cash especially with rounding errors. Just present the data as you see fit but do the maths in cents, pennies, ...

Comment: ok, i am in my infancy with js, so i will be researching storing in cents like you say, i dont know how to do but will learn if it is the smartest and best method. thank you

Comment: I made a mistake - JS does not use integers. But take heed on rounding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
.toFixed(2);
```

on the grand total

Like:

```
1.23898.toFixed(2); // 1.24
```

Comment: i cant believe it was that simple, thank you so much

Comment: @gomoguy You're welcome. Make sure you accept it as answer so that others can benefit from it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want smt like this: 1.23756 -> 1.24 ?
Then you can use `toFixed(num)`

```
var num = 1.23756;
console.log(num.toFixed(2)); // 1.24
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp):
Convert a number into a string, keeping only two decimals:

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n=num.toFixed(2);
```

The result of n will be:

```
5.57
```

Comment: If you are going to use floats (IMHO is stupid for currency) you sometimes need to round up or down.Some customers get annoyed when they are feeling they are diddled out of a cent - because in their head they think - What else am I losing out of/

Comment: again thank for the honest input. i will learn the proper method and try to implement it

Comment: @EdHeal not only that, it could also be a legal problem.

Comment: @EdHeal IMHO when it comes to money anything less than cents is meaningless to customers and in real daily transactions (buying/selling) you won't be dealing with such small values. the problem usually raises when you are converting currencies which i think a little money loss (less than a cent) is accepted by both parties (rounding up or down).

Comment: @hkazemi - Consider a person making thousands of transactions per day and just before going home has to balance the books. A thousand pennies is a good meal out for two. Then that person get a little annoyed with being sacked

Comment: @EdHeal yes you are right. i am working for a bank which is making thousands of transaction per day but actually in long term loss/gain is balanced and some individuals loose or gain a little money. and our bank doesn't loose or gain money. chances for rounding up/down are 50/50. it is a fair solution not a exact one. so we are both right. i am fair and you are being exact. BTW, i like your point of view.

Comment: @hkazemi - Also consider when you 'phone a company on one of there numbers that charge you and have to listen to a message for 10 secs. May cost you a penny but for the company that is a lot of cash. They have load of those pennies per minute. Soon build up

Comment: @hkazemi - I would like to see the evidence for this assertion. I have never seen a poor bookmarker or banker

Comment: @hkazemi - Also surprised that a bank uses Javascript to do financial transactions

Comment: sorry this started some conflict. I am researching a way to run it accurately. This may be an internal invoicing system, but even for our own, I have to be diligent about the accuracy.

Comment: @hkazemi every time you are doing money calculations with floats your are prone to have inaccuracies, for a customer it is probably not a problem. But it could not only be a problem with the tax authorities if the tax is not calculated correctly but also legal problem if the result is higher due the calculation errors in the end, as it does not reflect the price advertised on page.

Comment: @EdHeal I am not telling that the bank is not gaining money at all. Their cut from converting currencies and other transactions is quite good. but they are not looking to gain money from rounding up/down. At least the bank I am working for isn't. PS: i like a lot of things, capitalism isn't one of them.

Comment: @hkazemi - Please run that past me again. A bank not interest in making money and employee working for a bank that is not into capitalism (despite a bank is the apex of capitalism